# Poisson equation on a square

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve with Mathematica the following problem $$-\Delta u = 10$$ on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.

I obtain the following plot with my own Matlab code,  but with Mathematica I can't even obtain the plot. Could anyone confirm if the same plot is obtained with your own version of Mathematica?

```
f = 10;
pde = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f;
bc = {u[x, 0]  == 0,
   u[x,1]  == 0,
   u[0, y] == 0,
   u[1, y] == 0
   };
DSolve[{pde, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}, Assumptions -> {0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you were doing this numerically in Matlab, so here's the equivalent in Mathematica

```
whee = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, u[x, y],
  {x, 0, 1},
  {y, 0, 1}
  ];
Plot3D[whee, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

To obtain the max

```
NMaximize[whee,  {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[]]

{0.736711, {x -> 0.500081, y -> 0.499919}}
```

Comment: Did you set $f=10$ in your code? @b3m2a1

Comment: @bobinthebox I just copy-pasted what was there

Comment: So, could you confirm that the commands in my Mathematica snippet are the right way to solve this simple problem? @b3m2a1 ?

Comment: @bobinthebox except use `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue` so you get a numerical solution...

Comment: Thanks for your time, I see now the problem. Before accepting your answer, I have a last curiosity: how can you see the maximum of the solution? For instance, with my own Matlab code, I obtain a maximum of $0.73$. @b3m2a1

Comment: @bobinthebox see the edit

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm still a beginner. Sorry for those dumb questions :-)

Comment: @bobinthebox dw about it. No way to learn without trying things out and asking question

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, I have to multiply the pde by $-1$ in order to get any results, Mathematica is just idiosyncratic.  Consider

```
f=10;
pde=Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}]==-f;
bc={u[x,0]==0,u[x,1]==0,u[0,y]==0,u[1,y]==0};
soln=DSolve[{pde,bc},u[x,y],{x,y}]
```

The result is a list of a list of rules, containing a rule which defines $u(x,y)$.  You can use `StringReplace[ToString[TeXForm@u[x,y]/.First@soln],{"K[1]"->"k"}]` to obtain
$$2 \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}-\frac{40 \text{sech}\left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  k\right) \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  k\right) \sin(\pi  x k) \sinh\left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (y-1) k\right) \sinh\left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  y k\right)}{\pi ^3 k^3}$$
We can make an approximate plot with

```
Plot3D[Sum[-80/(\[Pi]^3 k^3)
Sech[(\[Pi] k)/2] Sin[(\[Pi] k)/2]^2
Sin[\[Pi] x k] Sinh[(\[Pi] (y - 1) k)/2] Sinh[(\[Pi] y k)/2],
{k, 1, 20}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

[image: soln]

Comment: It seems pretty close to mine. Could you tell me what's the maximum of the solution ? @Adam

Comment: My guess is the idiosyncrasy comes from the fact that `DSolve` has to reduce its PDE argument down to something that can be structurally compared to a set of templates it has built in. I'm sure the `-Laplacian` is just messing with that

Comment: It's not too hard to show $\partial_xu(1/2,1/2)=\partial_yu(1/2,1/2)=0$ with Mathematica, which shows $(1/2,1/2)$ is a local max.  Showing its a global max is harder; not sure if Mathematica can do this without manual work.

Comment: @b3m2a1 `Laplacian` seems to work ok; even `DSolving` with `-D[D[u[x,y],x],x]-D[D[u[x,y],y],y]==f` fails (while `D[D[u[x,y],x],x]+D[D[u[x,y],y],y]==-f` works just as well as `Laplacian`)

Comment: @Adam my comment isn't about `Laplacian`, per se, but about putting the _negative_ of the differential operator on the left _in this specific case_. As I said, `DSolve` compares structurally against a set of templates and it clearly isn't ready for that one. I'd report it to WRI